# Why isn't there any non-parisian-accent journalists at French TV/radio?

Tags: politique, accents-régionaux, radio, télévision

France mainland accents are [various](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accents_r%C3%A9gionaux_en_France), however only the standard accent —which is the middle-class Parisian accent— is present in French TV/radio channels which target the whole mainlanders, illustrating the domination of Paris over the rest of France.

Is it just a "tradition" with unsaid employment criterion over journalists or is it officially ruled with some texts?
I mean, e.g.:

- Is there a proper legal text saying that national french TV journalists should talk with this Parisian accent? Or do the TV journalist job adverts explicitly ask for this Parisian accent? If yes, isn't it discriminatory?
- Do teachers have to teach the standard accent at school? Does the reference school books mention that e.g. such a vowel should be pronounced with the standard accent?

My question is about the regional factor ("Parisian" referring to region ile-de-France) but not about the social class factor.

Comment: To be accurate, it's called a standard French accent, not a Parisian accent. The “standard French” is the **French spoken in the greater Paris region of Île-de-France**. Historically, this was where the French kings lived. https://www.thelocal.fr/20200708/france-regional-accents-parisian-why-are-french-people-so-snobbish-when-it-comes-to-regional-accents/ Many online articles decry the fact that regional accents are not acceptable in media.

Comment: Probably for the same reason that, until a decade or two ago, all the announcers on the BBC spoke Received Pronunciation, and that you don't hear any strong Southern or New York accents on US television news. Judging from the BBC's experience, this is due to totally unjustified prejudices on the part of the people running the channels—nothing bad happened when they started allowing regional accents on the BBC.

Comment: thanks @Lambie I modified the introduction to precise what I meant.

Comment: On the other hand, rugby consultants **must** have south-western french accent (Toulouse's prefered).

Comment: @Lambie - I decided to copy my pronunciation from JPP, and a lady on a TGV asked me if I was Swiss. For a Rosbif, that's a result! Alas, he is with us no more, I just found out, and I am quite upset.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sorry, not getting JPP. :)

Comment: @Lambie - very well known in France https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Pierre_Pernaut

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely no legal text, targetting journalists, teachers (all sorts of accents heard among teachers, depends where they come from) or anyone else.  Besides I don't think you are using ["Parisian" accent](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parler_parisien) correctly, I expect you mean, having no accent... or what is said to be a "neutral" accent... or what is supposed to be the "best" French accent ([Tourangeau](https://www.nouvelobs.com/rue89/rue89-rue89-culture/20110704.RUE3199/l-accent-de-tours-le-plus-pur-de-france-bah-plus-tant-qu-ca.html) has this reputation).  I have noticed that sports journalists and weather people have a regional accent more often than other sorts of journalists (I do mean on national channels).

Journalists on national radio and television seem to have the same accent not only because regional accents have been slowly disappearing over the last 60-80 years but also for cultural reasons. Regional accents are not supposed to be "nice" and are discriminated against.

> *30 millions de Français ont un accent régional et que 10 millions d'entre elles estiment qu'elles ont été discriminées au cours de leurs études ou au cours de leur carrière professionnelle en raison de leur accent*<sup>1</sup>.

This article (2017) [*Rythme, intensité, accent : comment les médias formatent la voix*](https://larevuedesmedias.ina.fr/rythme-intensite-accent-comment-les-medias-formatent-la-voix) in "La revue des médias" deals with this subject.

Jean-Michel Aphatie, one of the rare French broadcast journalists who has a regional accent wrote a book<sup>2</sup> denouncing this uniformity. There have been numerous reviews of this book, in [this one](https://www.franceinter.fr/societe/avoir-un-accent-une-discrimination-ignoree) on France Inter we can find the following quote from the book which partly answers your question:

> *Les écoles de journalisme expliquent que les grandes rédactions leur demandent d'envoyer des gens sans accent, ce qui est une stupidité, tout le monde a un accent, mais avec l'accent standard. Les directions de chaines de télévision nous disent : ce sont les écoles de journalistes qui nous envoient des gens formatés. Évidemment, la responsabilité principale, ce sont les chaînes de radio et de télévision qui ne promeuvent pas aux postes les plus exposés des personnes avec une diversité d'accents. Les étudiants ne sont pas idiots. Quand ils ont un accent régional ou un accent social, soit ils vont se corriger d'eux-mêmes, soit ils vont s'orienter vers la presse écrite.*

This 2017 podcast on Arte radio [*Il faut trouver la voie*](https://www.arteradio.com/son/61658634/et_la_c_est_le_drame) is also quite interesting.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Quoted from the article on [3](https://www.franceinter.fr/societe/avoir-un-accent-une-discrimination-ignoree) : *Avoir un accent, une discrimination ignorée*.

<sup>2</sup> Jean-Michel Aphatie, Michel Feltin-Palas : *J'ai un accent, et alors*. Michel Lafon, 2020.</sup>

Comment: I used "Parisian accent" and not "neutral accent" by purpose, because it is neutral for Parisians only. This question is about why there is (should be) a standard accent and how it is translated into the media/school and how France deals with the representation of the diversity of French accents.
Thanks for the other paragraphs/references, they are great.

Comment: @Noil There's a Parisian accent (or there used to be...) and it is not neutral, like all regional accents it has particularities and it is not the one heard in the media. Unless you mean the accent spoken by the *bourgoisie* in Paris, which indeed is probably very close to the one spoken in the media, it doesn't have the Parisian peculiarities.  You are asking " how it is translated into the media/school and how France deals with the representation of the diversity of French accents " which is exactly what the second quote is about, I wouln't say it better. The Arte podcast as well.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you, I've just edited my post to take this into account and used  "upper-class Parisian accent" to characterize the standard accent instead of "Parisian accent".

Comment: I wouldn't use "upper-class", "middle-class" is more like it.

Comment: That's right. Definitely not upper class per se.